# How does AspectJ match @annotation advice expression with an annotation even when the expression in a different case (small case)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, aspectj

```java
@Auditable(value=1)
public ResponseEntity upload(@RequestParam file){
    // Code
}
```

This code is using an @Auditable annotation given below:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Auditable {
    Integer value() default 0;
}
```

I have an aspect as follows

```java
@Before("@annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(Integer auditable) {
  AuditCode code = auditable;
  // ...
}
```

In the above example how is the `@Auditable` expression being matched to `@annotation(auditable)` expression even though the A letter in `@Auditable` is in uppercase whereas in `@annotation(auditable)` the letter a is in lowercase?

I tried reading the documentation but it just presents the facts without explaining the boundaries of annotation expression matching and in what scenarios it can fail. I was expecting the annotation matching to be case sensitive but I think something deeper is going on like object creation of the `@Auditable` annotation and then that object is somehow being matched with the Aspect.

Comment: using a case insensitive String comparison, I imagine

Comment: @Jorn Yeah thats the probable answer. But I can't get any docs where it is explicitly mentioned. I just want to be sure.

Comment: No, that was a guess, but not the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotations in Spring AOP or AspectJ are matched by their types. The syntax is

- either `@annotation(my.package.MyAnnotation)`
- or `@annotation(myAnnotationParameter)` in combination with an advice parameter like `MyAnnotation myAnnotationParameter`, e.g.

```java
@Before("@annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(Auditable auditable) {
  System.out.println(auditable.value());
  // ...
}
```

or, if you need the joinpoint,

```java
@Before("@annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(JoinPoint joinPoint, Auditable auditable) {
  System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + auditable.value());
  // ...
}
```

If the annotation parameter is bound to an advice parameter like this, its name in the advice method signature and in the pointcut should exactly match, i.e. in a case-sensitive way.

But your example does not make any sense, and I doubt that you found it in any tutorial like that:

```java
@Before("@annotation(auditable)")
public void audit(Integer auditable) { // ⚡
  AuditCode code = auditable;          // ⚡
  // ...
}
```

This would not match, because `Integer` is not an annotation type. It would not even compile, because you cannot assign an `Integer` to whatever type `AuditCode` is meant to be - unless `AuditCode` happens to be an `Integer` subclass, which is impossible because `Integer` is a final class.

Next time, please do not post untested pseudo code that you wrote directly on Stack Overflow, but code you actually compiled and ran on your local machine.